# Spark RDD/DF as variable member of class. Does it affect performance?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, serialization

I would like to ask one theoretical question.

Imagine we have our main Object as:

```
val pathToFile: String = "/some/path/to/file.csv" 
val rddLoader: RddLoader = new RddLoader(pathToFile)
val rdd = rddLoader.load()
def transformer = new Transformer(rdd)
transformer.transform1(someOtherRdd)
transformer.transform2(yetAnotherRdd)
```

And out Transformer defined as (pseudo code)

```
class Transformed(rdd: RDD[sruct]) {

  val rddToTransform = rdd.someTransformation

  def complexTransformations1(anotherRdd: RDD[struct]) = {
     rddToTransform.complexTransformationsInvlovingAnotherRdd
  }

  def complexTransformations2(anotherRdd: RDD[struct]) = {
     rddToTransform.complexTransformations2InvlovingAnotherRdd
  }
}
```

Will the fact that rddToTransfrom is member of class thus member of instance of the class impact performance. I guess the whole class will be serialized. But will this cause rddToTransform be serialized for each partition thus multiple times.

Will the below be better in terms of performance, overhead seriallization, etc. In it we are using an Object and our RDD is not member of a class but just passed as parameter to method.

```
val pathToFile: String = "/some/path/to/file.csv" 
val rddLoader: RddLoader = new RddLoader(pathToFile)
val rdd = rddLoader.load()
def transformer = Transformer
transformer.transform1(rdd, someOtherRdd)
transformer.transform2(rdd, yetAnotherRdd)


object Transformer {

  def complexTransformations1(rdd, anotherRdd: RDD[struct]) = {
     rddToTransform.complexTransformationsInvlovingAnotherRdd
  }

  def complexTransformations2(rdd, anotherRdd: RDD[struct]) = {
     rddToTransform.complexTransformations2InvlovingAnotherRdd
  }
}
```

I can give an example with broadcast variables. I understand their way of working I am just wondering if what is explained  below would apply also to RDDs and if we need to avoid using RDDs as in the first example (member of class)

Let's say we have a large dataset, with 420 partitions and a cluster of 8 executor nodes. In an operation like:

```
val referenceData = Map(...)
val filtered = rdd.filter(elem => referenceData.get(elem) > 10)
```

The referenceData object will be serialized 420 times, or as many tasks as are required to execute the transformation.

Instead, a broadcast variable:

```
val referenceDataBC = sparkContext.broadcast(Map(...))
val filtered = rdd.filter(elem => referenceDataBC.value.get(elem) > 10)
```

will be sent once to each executor, or 8 times total. Hence, saving a lot of network and CPU by reducing the serialization overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, in normal case broadcast variables are better memory optimisations but there are cases where they are not usable.

To understand better:

Apache Spark has two types abstractions. The main abstraction Spark provides is Resilient Distributed Dataset(RDD) and another is Shared Variables.

Shared variables:
Shared variables are the variables that are required to be used by many functions & methods in parallel. Shared variables can be used in parallel operations.

Spark segregates the job into the smallest possible operation, a closure, running on different nodes and each having a copy of all the variables of the Spark job. Any changes made to these variables doesn’t reflect in the driver program and hence to overcome this limitation Spark provides two special type of shared variables – Broadcast Variables and Accumulators.

**Broadcast variables:** 
Used to cache a value in memory on all nodes. Here only one instance of this read-only variable is shared between all computations throughout the cluster.
Spark sends the broadcast variable to each node concerned by the related task. After that, each node caches it locally in serialised form.
Now before executing each of the planned tasks instead of getting values from the driver system retrieves them locally from the cache.
Broadcast variables are:

**Immutable (Unchangeable), 
Distributed i.e. broadcasted to the cluster, 
Fit in memory**

**Accumulators:** 
As its name suggests Accumulators main role is to accumulate values. The accumulator is variables that are used to implement counters and sums. Spark provides accumulators of numeric type only.
The user can create named or unnamed accumulators.
Unlike Broadcast Variables, accumulators are writable. However, written values can be only read in driver program. It’s why accumulators work pretty well as data aggregators.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anush for the detailed answer! It's appreciated.
Maybe I didn't ask my question right. I am aware of the pros of using broadcast variables, shared variables and accumulators. I gave the case for the broadcast variables as an example.

I was wondering if `rddToTransform` would be seriallized for each task like in the case we are not using broadcast variable as it is is a member of a class that needs to be Seriallized? I will edit my question and will show alternative approach. I am wondering if there is difference.
Thanks!
Dimitar

Comment: @MitakaJ9: RDDs are distributed data structures, All tasks need not have complete RDD they will only have one one chunk or partition.

Comment: I tought so too. But I started wondering that all tasks need to have the class Transformer as it has methods that are being used in transformations of RDDs. And rddToTransform is member of this class so could it get transferred to all tasks along with the Transformer class? 
Thanks!

Comment: @MitakaJ9 True, just that this code is looked by Driver first and spark framework does lot of things under the hood such as query optimisation, creating partitions of the RDDs and then communication between all the distributed executors etc so loosely speaking you can think that this code is compiled or interpreted differently and at that step your rddToTransform is more appropriately represented.

Comment: Thanks than I can sleep safely :)